# Image is not removed when visibility is set to false

Tags: apache-flex, bitmap, flex4, sprite, tweener

I'm working on a project where there is an Image (spark or mx) and when I set the visibility to false it still remains! It seems to dim instead of remove. I'm thinking that maybe something, a sprite or display object somewhere or some graphics command is somehow capturing a screen grab while the image is visible and leaving a phantom image. I can't track it down. Has anyone heard of this?

I'm using Tweener and I think it may have something to do with it but again it's a large project and this problem is nested deep within it.

**UPDATE**
I think it has to do with Tweener. I removed the tweens and visibility started to work as described. I think it may have been that Flex defers committing the value of a property and it's effect until the render event. So it maybe set to false but it may not actually be invisible until the next validation / render phase while Tweener does it's thing right away.

I commented out the Tweener and other code related to it for now and I'm not going to put more resources into it tracking it at this time.

Comment: have you tryied setting includeInLayout to false ?

Comment: A lot of effects tend to set `cacheAsBitmap` to true. You might try setting that to false before you change the visibility.

Comment: Sunil - I think it had something to do with that and Tweener. I updated my post message describing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it in a container?  I have not had a problem setting visible=false and it still being displayed.  As jidma said, try includeInLayout, another thing to try is setting the parent visible=false